# Color in R plot

Tags: r, colors

I have this tab called x:

[image]

I use it to make this plot, using the script:

```
lg <- x[1,2]
plot(1, type="n", xlab=contig, ylab="Best hits", xlim=c(-200, lg), ylim=c(0, 11))
segments(0,0,lg,0, col="red", lwd=3)
for (i in 1:10) {
  segments(x[i,3],i,x[i,4],i); text(x=(x[i,4]-x[i,5]/2),y=i+0.2,labels=paste(x[i,6],"-",x[i,13], "%"))
}
```

[image]

But I'd like to have the text (starting by "NW_...") to be colored in the plot so that each **unique** text has its own color.
Here since there are 5 unique "NW_", there would be five colors.

I tried:

```
lg <- x[1,2]
plot(1, type="n", xlab=contig, ylab="Best hits", xlim=c(-200, lg), ylim=c(0, 11))
segments(0,0,lg,0, col="red", lwd=3)
for (i in 1:10) {
  segments(x[i,3],i,x[i,4],i); text(x=(x[i,4]-x[i,5]/2),y=i+0.2,labels=paste(x[i,6],"-",x[i,13], "%"), col=rainbow(n=nlevels(x$TID))[x$TID])
}
```

But this fails.
Actually, I have no clue how to make this in a loop.
Could you help?

Thanks!

Muriel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add a colour column to `x`.

```
x$colour <- rainbow(nlevels(x$TID))[x$TID]
```

Then use this colour in your for loop.

```
lg <- x[1,2]
plot(1, type="n", xlab=contig, ylab="Best hits", xlim=c(-200, lg), ylim=c(0, 11))
segments(0,0,lg,0, col="red", lwd=3)
for (i in 1:10) {
  segments(x[i, 3], i, x[i, 4], i)
  text(
    x = (x[i, 4] - x[i, 5] / 2),
    y = i + 0.2,
    labels = paste(x[i, 6], "-", x[i, 13], "%"),
    col=x[i, "colour"])
}
```